# run premade animation with script

Tags: python, animation, scripting

Total newbie here,how can I run an animation when the left mouse button is pressed? (this means in-game, not in the engine itself.) I found some old tutorials but they don't work anymore. Also, how can I run my blender project?

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting and is considered rude.

Comment: I just put it for more emphasis so people know what I mean.

Comment: That emphasis isn't necessary though, a more effective tactic would be to write clear and concisely. Also is this even a question about Blender? You talk about the animation being in a game engine which is activated by a left click. I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to make it so that when I do a left click, it plays a certain animation. It may have to do with scripting or not, I have no idea.

Comment: there, I removed the "emphasis"

Comment: Hi, are you meaning to use the old BGE that was removed in version 2.8? Most here are likely going to assume you are reffering to the current version of blender unless you specify otherwise. Also just a hint..if you really need to use *emphasis* then you can do `*this*`(*italic*) or `**this**` (**bold**)instead of caps. :)

Comment: ok thanks! I am running version 2.83.4.